# TinyMCE causing insecure items warning to appear over SSL

Tags: iframe, ssl, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and have an email template that uses http:// images.  The page is SSL but I keep getting the page has insecure items because of the http:// of the images which are held on an external site.  I change it to https:// and that insecure warning goes away.  Is there a way around this?